# Accessing nested objects (and its data) in a map function

Tags: javascript

So I have an Object Array that looks like this:

[image: Object Array]

I then use a map function to create my html render string like this:

```
var renderBottles =  bottleArray.map(bottle => (
  <div> {bottle.bottleId} - {bottle.qty} <a href='#' onClick={ () => this.props.store.del(0)}>X</a></div>
))
```

This all works just fine!

I would like, however, to access that first object during my map loop.

[image: Highlighted object]

Because I'm working with firebase, that name is random, so my question is: How do I reference that object based on its location in the Object Array AND how do I retrieve the nested data all the while in the map function?

Is that even possible?

[image: Nested Object Data]

I've been fiddling with this for a while now not getting anywhere, would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it completely random ? or will it contains any thing common

Comment: That value is auto-generated by firebase so, although it isn't COMPLETELY random, I don't think it should be counted as 'predictable' in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If the requested object is the only value of type `object` you could do

```
for(var key in bottle) {
    if(typeof bottle[key] === 'object') {
       // bottle[key] is the desired object
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I'm quoting the same comment I made above as I think it applies here too: I've tried similar approaches and it does work to some extent (I can retrieve the nested object data) but I still can't 'merge' it with the other pertinent information whilst in the map function.

If i did {bottle.-KbseOJMQkbUafy9rvJo.discountedPrice} in my map function it would work so I'm looking for a workaround on the likes of {bottle.[0].discountedPrice} if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using ES6 language. If the random key'd object is the only object within the array-collection, you can now do the below:

```
for (let key in bottleArray) {
  if(typeof bottleArray[key] === 'object') {
       let innerObj = bottleArray[key];
       //use innerObj['discountedPrice'] etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I've tried similar approaches and it does work to some extent (I can retrieve the nested object data) but I still can't 'merge' it with the other pertinent information whilst in the map function.

If i did {bottle.-KbseOJMQkbUafy9rvJo.discountedPrice} in my map function it would work so I'm looking for a workaround on the likes of {bottle.[0].discountedPrice} if you catch my drift.